# Rust Polars: Merging columns into a map (List of Structs)

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm trying to merge a number of columns from a Polars data frame (in Rust) into a format compatible with the `MAP` type in Parquet. I believe this means converting the columns into a single column containing a list of structs, each with a `key` and a `value` field. In other words:

```
List(Struct([Field('key', Utf8), Field('value', Utf8)]))
```

This is how Polars reads in Parquet files that have been written in this format, so I think it stands to reason that writing back to that format should work.

I'm struggling to work out exactly how to do it though and can't find any Rust examples of doing anything similar. Can anyone point me in the right direction?